# how to avoid error during bower installation?

Tags: node.js, bower

I am trying to install bower in windows 7:

```
npm install bower -g
```

It returns with this error:

```
error Error: No compatible version found: bower-endpoint-parser@'^0.2.2'
1073 error Valid install targets:
1073 error ["0.1.0-rc.1","0.1.0","0.2.0","0.2.1","0.2.2"]
1073 error     at installTargetsError (C:\Users\myname\node-0.10.4\node-0.10.4\node_modules\npm\lib\cache.js:685:10)
1073 error     at C:\Users\myname\node-0.10.4\node-0.10.4\node_modules\npm\lib\cache.js:607:10
1073 error     at saved (C:\Users\myname\node-0.10.4\node-0.10.4\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-registry-client\lib\get.js:138:7)
1073 error     at Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)
1074 error If you need help, you may report this log at:
1074 error     <http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>
1074 error or email it to:
1074 error     <npm-@googlegroups.com>
1075 error System Windows_NT 6.1.7601
1076 error command "C:\\Users\\myname\\node-0.10.4\\node-0.10.4\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\myname\\node-0.10.4\\node-0.10.4\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "bower"
1077 error cwd C:\Users\myname\BowerJS
1078 error node -v v0.10.4
1079 error npm -v 1.2.18
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a pretty old version of NPM (1.2). NPM notoriously has problems with Windows, e.g. because of long file paths which are not allowed on Windows.

First try cleaning the cache and retrying with `npm -g cache clean` and then update npm before other steps

Comment: I tried npm update -g what is the latest npm anyway?

Comment: the major version is v3, but v2 should be also ok. maybe you will need to reinstall if it is not unable to skip major versions